# Getting XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES exception in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Getting `XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES` while trying to execute the following statements:

```
    (dls:document-update($uri,$content,"Main Document Updated",fn:true(),xdmp:default-permissions(),$content-collection), 
     dls:document-checkin($uri, fn:true()),
     dls:document-update($sub-uri,$sub-content,"sub Document Updated",fn:true(),xdmp:default-permissions(),$content-sub-collection),
     dls:document-checkin($sub-uri, fn:true()),
     cin:update-version ($sub-uri))

     declare function cin:update-version ($sub-uri){
      let $id := xs:int(fn:doc($sub-uri)//id)
      return
       xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc($sub-uri)//id,element id {fn:sum(($id,1))})
      };
```

Little confused with the transaction rule for multi statements transaction. As the lock on the document is already released. why should it have any problem in doing node replace on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code won't run as written because of syntax errors: there are missing variables and there is a function after the expression body. But looking past that, there is nothing here to suggest a multi-statement transaction. Instead this looks like a single statement, and so the multiple updates to `$uri` conflict with each other. The call to `dls:document-update` updates `$uri` and then `dls:document-checkin` tries to update the same document in the same transaction, causing a conflict. The same logic applies to `$sub-uri`. In the docs, http://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-update notes that "This function must be called in a separate transaction from the dls:document-checkout and dls:document-checkin".

MarkLogic transactions behave differently than you might expect, because XQuery is not an imperative or procedural language. Try reading up on transactions at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions

In most cases I prefer to write separate transactions as separate requests, but here is the first part of your query written using semicolons to separate transactions. You might try rewriting the same code in `xdmp:commit` style, to understand the difference.

```
(: multiple statements with semicolons :)
(: statement 1 :)
import module namespace dls="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"
 at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

declare variable $content := <test>content</test>;
declare variable $content-collection := "content";
declare variable $uri := "test";

dls:document-update(
  $uri,
  $content,
  "Main Document Updated",
  fn:true(),
  xdmp:default-permissions(),
  $content-collection) ;

(: statement 2 :)
import module namespace dls="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"
 at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

declare variable $uri := "test";

dls:document-checkin($uri, fn:true())
```

Comment: All the variables are set prior to this in the same xquery. I just pasted the code fragment which had problem. dls:document-checkout is separately called in separate transaction.  The first four statements i.e update and chekin of uri and sub-uri worked fine. Problem came when only xdmp:node-replace operation was introduced on sub-uri. So is it not the problem of multiple statements under same transaction? Only solution would be segregating dls:document-update, dls:document-checkin and xdmp:node-replace into separate transactions?

Comment: Not sure what else I can add. You have a single statement with conflicting updates. You can try to rework it to remove the conflict, or you can use a multi-statement transaction. If you go to MST, I think `xdmp:commit` is better than semicolons.